# How to pass variable data into div in JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, variables

I want after Ajax success I can pass data from `id=use` into `div id=app`.
This is my script:

```
$.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"process3.php",
        data:params,
        cache:false,
        async:false,
        success: function(data){
                       switch(data){
                             case 1:
                                     $("#dialog").dialog('close');
                                     $("#segment").show();
                                     $("#appdate").text(today);
                                     $("#app").text($("#use").val());
                                     break;
                              //case 2:
                              }
                           //do next job after success
                        }
                  });
```

But it seems not work. The data can't show inside the div.
Could you tell me why it's happen? How to fix that?

---

This is the html:

```
<td class="space">
       <div id="app"></div><br/>
       <div id="appdate"></div>
</td>

<input type="text" id="use" name="use">
```

---

server side script:

```
$sql = "SELECT Privilege FROM admin WHERE user='".$Use."' AND password='".$Pass."'";
echo $sql;
$data=mysql_query($sql) or die(_ERROR26.": ".mysql_error());
if($data){
                $priv = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

                /*  will return 1 or 2 depending on the privilage set in you DB where 1 is admin and 2 is user */
                echo $priv['privilege'];  
                }else{
                        echo 0; // If login fails
                        }
```

whether my server side get different result?

Comment: if you do `function(data){alert(data);` what you have ?

Comment: it's show `SELECT Privilege FROM admin WHERE user='Indra' AND password='21633'`. I put alert before switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the server side become:

```
 $sql = "SELECT Privilege FROM admin WHERE user='".$Use."' AND password='".$Pass."'";
 $data=mysql_query($sql) or die(_ERROR26.": ".mysql_error());
 $dat=mysql_fetch_array($data,MYSQL_NUM);
        if(mysql_affected_rows()>0) {
                        echo $dat[0];
                        }else{
                        echo "No specified data";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the data returned by the ajax request is a string. You may have compare in the correct type in order to switch..case

```
switch(parseInt(data)){
  case 1 : /////.......
    ;
}
```

or

```
switch(data){
  case "1" : //........
     ;
}
```

Comment: This Ajax return numeric value 1,2, or 3.

Comment: Have you tried what I suggested to you ? If you're doing a kind of `<?php echo 1 ?>` on the server side, it will be transfered as text though.

Comment: In other words, are you sure your code is running : first in your success callback, and second in your first case statement ?